# how do network interfaces get setup at startup on macos

Tags: network

Does anybody know how network interfaces get setup at startup? I see a lot of random interfaces, and would like to turn these off

Comment: What problem do you believe you are correcting by doing this?

Comment: I am just interested in answer to the question. Theres a lot of benefits. Do you have an answer to the question?

Comment: @Marc Wilson asks a valid question. AD is designed to offer troubleshooting help with Apple products not to write articles on how various parts of the OS work on a low level. We can help you if you have a *specific problem.* So add that specific problem you are trying to solve to your original question, so that we can assist.

Comment: @CarriMegrabyan That's fine, what are those benefits?  Edit them into your question.

Comment: where can I find more information about this, if not AD?

Comment: I appreciate your replies.